# Browsing an object's fields

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, nsnull

In Objective C, I have an object e.g. `Person` with a lot of fields `firstName`, `lastName`, `phoneNumber`, `address`, `city`... and so on. These fields types are `NSString` and any of these could be `nil`.

Now I want to concatenate my field values in another `NSString` :

```
Person *p = ...
NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSString *field in @[p.firstName, p.lastName, p.phoneNumber,
                          p.adress, p.city, ....more fields...]) {
    if ([field length] > 0) {
        [s appendFormat:@"%@\n", field];
    }
}
```

Issue is that this code crash whenever one of the field is `nil`. I have the exception :

```
[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object 
from objects[0]'
```

How could I handle simply the case of `nil` values within my `for` loop ?

Comment: Edited my question for clarity : there will be a lot of fields in the object (around 15)

Comment: Okay, that means I have to change my answer :)

Comment: @Tom Yep, sorry, my example was too specific.

Comment: I saw my vote count go up and then down.  Someone voted me down, and I lost 2 rep points.. Anyway I updated my answer to make it more complete.

Comment: Not me, voted you up and kept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @TomPace's post, for this small number I would do a simple if/else.

However, there may be times you do need to loop through a list of fields.

It's a bad idea to blindly pull the values into an array as you could be trying inserting `nil` values into the array. In this case, it would be better to place the field names into a key array as strings and loop through the list using `valueForKey:` to access the values. I would possibly store the `keys` list somewhere else where it can be used again.

```
Person *p = ...
NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

NSArray *keys = @[@"firstName", @"lastName", @"phoneNumber", @"adress", @"city"];

for (NSString *key in keys) 
{
    NSString *value = [p valueForKey:key];
    if ([value length] > 0) {
        [s appendFormat:@"%@\n", value];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a selection of fields this small, don't use a for loop.

You may be saving a bit of code by attempting the for-loop structure, but it's really not the way to go if you're building the NSArray with only a few fields, and especially because you **can't put nil items in it**.

A better way to go is:

```
Person *p = ...
NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
if ([p.firstName length] > 0)   [s appendFormat:@"%@\n", p.firstName];
if ([p.lastName length] > 0)    [s appendFormat:@"%@\n", p.lastName];
if ([p.phoneNumber length] > 0) [s appendFormat:@"%@\n", p.phoneNumber];
if ([p.adress length] > 0)      [s appendFormat:@"%@\n", p.adress];
if ([p.city length] > 0)        [s appendFormat:@"%@\n", p.city];
```

---

**Edit**, after original Question was updated with large amount of fields.
Like @BergQuester said, an approach to support a larger, arbitrary set of fields is using KVO-style inspection.

```
NSArray *fieldNames = @[@"firstName", @"lastName", @"phoneNumber", ....more fields...];
NSString *field;
for (NSString *fieldName in fieldNames) {
    field = [p valueForKey:fieldName];
    if ([field length] > 0 ) {
        [s appendFormat: @"%@\n", field];
    }
}
```

Comment: The `> 0` is redundant (not wrong, just pointing out another stylistic option.)

Comment: @AaronBrager thanks, yes you're right. I guess I was just following the style of the original question. I prefer the omission myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
person.firstName = nil;
person.lastName = @"lastName";

NSMutableString *s = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
[s appendFormat:@"%@\n", person.firstName == nil?@"":person.firstName];
[s appendFormat:@"%@\n",  person.lastName == nil?@"":person.lastName];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the getters of the class `Person`.

```
    @implementation Person

    - (NSString *)firstName{
        if (_firseName == nil)
             _firstName = @"";
        return _firstName;
    }
///....Other setters    

    @end
```

Like this you can define all your setters here.

Comment: Those are getters, not setters.

Comment: Also, this solution wastes memory and could have negative side effects.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create `NSMutableString` category

```
#import "NSMutableString+checkForNilObject.h"

@implementation NSMutableString (checkForNilObject)


-(void) appendNotNillObject:(NSString *) string
{
    if(string)
    {
       [self appendString:string];
    }
}
@end
```